# generalization of isometry

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, isometry

[image]

An Isometry in the isomorphism of metric spaces, meaning it preserves all properties of a metric space.
Is there a generalization of an Isometry which talks about metric spaces that are the same up to a factor by a scalar?
For example, if we look at a circle with radius one and a circle with radius two as sub matric spaces of $R^2$, they are 'almost the same'. They have basically the same structure just that one is factored by two. This is a stronger similarity than just saying that their topological space is isomorphic.

Is there a definition that captures this similarity?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-isometry

Comment: In normed vector spaces, you have the group of dilations (homothety+translation).

Comment: @MoisheKohan I think that is a weaker definition than what I am talking about, but that is the name I would use :)

Comment: @Bernard that does seem like the same idea of what I am talking about, I wonder why it is defined for a normed space and not a metric one

Comment: You need e vector space structure to define a homothety and a translation.

Comment: @Bernard  right, but the same idea can be extended

Comment: @Bernard found one here: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Similarity_(geometry)#/Similarity_in_general_metric_spaces , there is a section about general metric spaces

Comment: I see. As I am not a specialist of topology, I don't know whether it has extensive developments, but I guess it is mainly useful in contexts where there's at least an implicit vector structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently it is called a similitude:
[image]

from: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Similarity_(geometry)#/Similarity_in_general_metric_spaces

Comment: although I'm not sure how the limit there is supposed to be defined

Comment: That's the right definition, although that writer chose an odd word for the terminology. I think most people just call it a similarity.